# How to verify text across HTML elements in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Given the following code, how would I verify the text within using Selenium?

```
<div class='my-text-block>
  <p>My first paragraph of text</p>
  <p>My second paragraph of text</p>
</div>
```

I am wanting to, in one verifyText statement to capture all the text:

> My first paragraph of text
>
> My second paragraph of text

Is it possible?

Comment: What are you trying to verify? That the text is present? That the text of paragraph one equals something specific and that the text of paragraph two equals something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've tagged this with selenium-webdriver, I'm assuming you want a code example but because you've not stated what language you're using, I'll give you a python example. It should be easy to translate that to a different language if needed.

```
ok(driver.find_element("class", "my-text-block").text == "What I expect it to be")
```

The text attribute on a `WebElement` object simply contains all visible text within that element and all children elements.

And some [lovely docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text), of course.

Comment: I'm using C#. But, yes, I can translate well enough. :)  driver.FindElement(IWebElement).Text() == "Expected text". Thanks!